# crispy Dilly beans

Tags: vegetables

I tried a new variety of green beans this year due to being powdery mildew resistant. 
I grew (Provider) beans. They are beautiful long, straight green beans. I made a batch of Dilly Beans, using my regular recipe and found them to be softer than I would have prefered and not a crisp as other beans I have use before. Has anyone else tried this variety of bean in canning and had this problem or know of a solution?

Comment: It's possible that calcium chloride (sold under the name 'Pickle Crisp') might help.  I'm not much of a canner myself (I only know about it from my mom)

Answer (score 1):

It is only a guess; but when I get close to using my vegetables, I crisp them up with a fresh cut and place them in warm water about 30 minutes prior to using them. Just as I would do to fresh cut flowers. When I grew green beans about 3 years ago, it worked like a charm and I semi-pickled them with no problems.

On the other hand, it has been a very hot summer in this neck of the woods as well as dry. Do you think that this could have contributed?

Here; someone asked the question: 
"What did I do wrong if my pickles aren't crisp or crunchy?" for green bean pickles.
http://www.pickyourown.org/greenbeans_pickled.htm

Very interesting Joe. In 2009, Ball took Pickle Crisp off of the market and due to the high demand; it was remarketed and improved. 
http://www.freshpreservingstore.com/ball-pickle-crisp-granules-5-5-oz/shop/382751/?CCAID=FPPTPD1PRDTL#details